# Re-render view without models changed backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i'm rendering a view from a collection of user.When a specific attribute(Status=online,offline) in a user change the view correctly show on the dom the value of attribute changed. But if i want render the view without the model in which the attribute is changed or viceversa add to view a model in wich attribute is changed?

This is a code that send to view a collection with users status online:

```
var user_on=Models.utenti.filter(function(model){
return model.get('status') === "on";            
});

var users_online = new Usercollection(user_on);
var page=new Homelistuser({model:users_online});  
this.changePage(page);
```

And this is a view:

```
var Homelistuser = Backbone.View.extend({

tagName: "ul",
id: "list",

template: Handlebars.compile(template),

    initialize: function () {
      Models=this.model;
      this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
      $(window).on('orientationchange', this.onOrientationChange);

    },


    render: function (eventName) {
      $(this.el).empty();
      _.each(this.model.models, function (ad) {


        $(this.el).append(new SingleUserView({
          model: ad
        }).render().el);
      }, this);
      return this;
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter online users in the `render` function of your view, I believe you called the `users_online` collection as `model` in it, so:

```
model.reset(model.filter(function(model){
  return model.get('status') === 'on';            
}));
```

or maybe just filter elements out as you append `SingleUserView`s

```
_.each(this.model.models, function (ad) {
  if (ad.get('status') !== 'on') return;
  $(this.el).append(new SingleUserView({
    model: ad
  }).render().el);
}, this);
```

Comment: Can you explane me what do reset method?

Comment: your code works:if an attribute user change from on to off its model deleted from dom but viceversa if attribute change from off to on its model doesn't add to model!i don't understand why!

Comment: The `reset` method resets the collection to the array argument you pass to it; make sure that when a model goes from off to on the `render` function gets called.